# Is this batch of sauerkraut salvageable?

Tags: food-safety, equipment, fermentation, sauerkraut

In researching sauerkraut recipes, I saw one could make it in a crock pot or jar covered with cheesecloth. Not having a suitable jar & not wanting to use my crock pot, I'm using a bowl & cheese cloth, checking for mold every day. I got on this site to find out why it doesn't like any fermentation is happening & if I can rinse it because is very salty. It's been 11 days, the cabbage is still crunchy & there is no foam. After reading various posts (thank you, all!) I'm wondering if it's an experimental batch I should throw out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My kraut doesn't always show signs of foaming, and, even though it is fermenting, it is relatively crisp. Further, 11 days is not very long. The container you use is not that important.  What is important is salt (and if you say it is "very salty" you probably have enough) and keeping the cabbage submerged. You will need to weigh it down so that all of the cabbage is under the liquid.  When you remove some with a clean utensil, what do your senses tell you?  If it feels slimy discard it.  If it smells bad, discard it. If you see fuzzy mold, you are better off starting over.  Otherwise, give it a taste.  My guess is that it is not very fermented after only a week and a half, so I would keep the experiment going.

Comment: Finally got back on this site, & realized I never did give an update: the sauerkraut turned out fantastic! Thanks again for the advice (you as well as well as Fermentation 4Ever). I will make another batch for sure.

Answer (score 1):

100 % keep going. Make sure you got cloth with something heavy on top of it to press the cabage. I do cloth, flat plate and a heavy jar filled with water to keep squeezing it down. Cloth has to be tuggen in not to let any outside matters in and liquid has to be above the cloth for about an inch or so. What ever floats above, remove together with the cloth, wipe the rims of pan, rinse the cloth in boiling water to kill unwanted bacteria and replace. You will be good.
I start chewing on it in about to weeks or so (when I wash the cloth I take some to use) and it tastes great. Not fully fermented but still great to eat (mind you, I make at least 20 liters per batch...)
You will have great cabbage as long as it is submerged, salted enough and weigh down.